# Accessing API using PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to access Json data from an API. Been doing research online but can't find the right resources for guidance. My documentation suggests doing the following but what method should I use to pull this data using PHP. This is what I have so far.

```
<?php

$header = array();
    $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';

    $header[] = 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode('MY_TOKEN_HERE'); 

    $url = "https://.../v1/StoreServices.svc";

    $ch = curl_init();


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //echo curl_error($ch);

  if ($response === false){
      echo "Failed";
      throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
  }
    print_r($response); 
?>
```

I'm getting a "Length Required HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length." error.

I've tried using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1); but then it takes me straight to the URL.

I've tried this with GET, still get an error or an endpoint error.

https://.../v1/StoreServices.svc/Json/Items/

Any suggestions?

Documentation suggests using this for authentication headers:

```
var token = "MY_TOKEN_HERE"; $.ajax ({… beforeSend: function (xhr) {   xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(token)); }, …);
```

And Sample Call:

```
var itemurl = "https://.../Json/Items/";
var token = "<your token here>";
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(token));
  },
  url: itemurl,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data, textStatus) { // your actions here }, error:     
  function (xhr, testStatus, errorThrown) { // } });
```

Comment: Is that the actual URL?

Comment: No it's not. It's a dummy url.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the backend requires that you send the content-length header. For that you need to add:

```
$header[] = 'Content-Length: 0';
```

Comment: That means that your request is now getting through to the application server, congratulations! Check the documentation you have been given or ask the people who provide the API how to deal with this error, because it's specific to their system.

Comment: Thanks for your help Joni.

Comment: Looks like it worked. I had to add /Json/Items/ to the end or the URL and change curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); to curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);